# Factory_girl_rails and postgres date format?

Tags: postgresql, date, ruby-on-rails-3.1, factory-bot, rails-postgresql

How do I format a date to put it in a factory_girl_rails factory eg:

```
Factory.define(:profile) do |t|
  t.length 110
  t.shipdate 1993-04-06
end
```

If it matters, I'm using postgresql and factory_girl_rails 1.0. The error I've been getting is `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "1982"` The rails version is 3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the quotes around your date string:

```
Factory.define(:profile) do |t|
  t.length 110
  t.shipdate '1993-04-06'
end
```

1993 minus 4 is 1989, 1989 minus 6 is 1983. Are you sure you copied the error message correctly?

Comment: @siggy_lxvi: How about we go with "temporarily blind to the obvious" instead?

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells us, that you tried to write the string `'1982'` to a date field, which is obviously not valid. A date needs a month and a day, too.

If you keep having input of that sort, you could process it with [`to_date()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html), which can make sense of it:

```
SELECT to_date('1982', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Result:

```
1982-01-01
```

There are a couple of [settings that influence processing of date/time values](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-FORMAT), most importantly `DateStyle`. An explicit cast with `to_date()` works independently, though.

Comment: 1982 isn't the date I'm trying to pass. The date is formatted as it appears in `t.shipdate 1993-04-06` which is effectively the same as your theoretical answer `1982-01-01` and ergo incorrect, as I am still getting the error message.

Comment: @siggy_lxvi: The error message is quite clear on that: you are trying to pass "1982" at some point.